# Как правильно обработать и обновить документы в MongoDB на NODE JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ecmascript

```
app.post('/api/getReports', (req, res)=>{
  let data = req.body.data; // Array of objects
  let reports = [];
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      db.collection('reports').find({}).toArray((err, res)=>{
        resolve(res);  
      });
  }).then((res)=>{
      res.forEach((item, index)=>{
         if(item.name === data.name) {
             let count = item.count + data.count;
             db.collection('reports').updateOne({name: item.name}, {$set: {count: count}});
         } else {
             db.collection('reports').insertOne(data)
         }        
      });
  })   
})
```

Как мне проверить новые полученные данные с ранее полученными данными в коллекции и сравнить если такая запись уже существует тогда к count этой записи прибавить только data.count если такая запись не существует то добавить в коллекцию?

Comment: Для чего вы используете цикл? Вам ведь надо только одну запись проверить на существование, так?

Comment: Дайте больше информации. Что из себя представляет `data`, например? Какие там объекты внутри?

Comment: В массиве хранятся объекты продуктов([{name: strawberry, price: 100, count: 3},... ]). Да одну запись надо проверять на существование внутри коллекции!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае, в виду неясности как выглядят сами `reports`:

```
app.post('/api/getReports', async (req, res) => {
        const { data } = req.body;
        const reports = db.collection('reports');
        try {
            for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                const report = await reports.findOne({name: data[i].name});
                if(report) {
                    await reports.updateOne({"_id": report._id}, {$inc: {count: data[i].count}})
                } else {
                    await reports.insertOne(data[i]);
                }
            }
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)    
        }
})
```

В случае, если `reports` это массив с объектами типа `{name: "ads", count: 12}`:

```
app.post('/api/getReports', async (req, res) => {
            const { data } = req.body;
            const reports = db.collection('reports');
            try {
                for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    await reports.updateOne({name: data[i].name}, {$inc: {count: data[i].count}},{upsert: true})         
                }
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err)    
            }
    })
```

Comment: решение -  "в лоб"

Comment: @Дмытрык А что не так с решениями в лоб в данном конкретном случае?

Comment: все норм.......

Comment: @Дмытрык Вопрос у автора неоднозначный. Или я его неправильно понял. Нет ясности как выглядят `reports`. Они такие же как и `data` или там только пара `name, count`.

Answer (score 2):

Имеем коллекцию:

```
{name: 'apple', count: 5},
{name: 'lemon', count: 4},
```

`db.test.updateOne({name: 'lemon'}, {$inc:{count:1}}, {upsert: true})` - этот запрос увеличит `count` у лимона

`db.test.updateOne({name: 'cucumber'}, {$inc:{count:1}}, {upsert: true})` - этот запрос добавит в коллекцию документ

Comment: Вы почитайте вопрос еще раз. Не надо `count` инкрементировать на 1, а прибавить надо `data.count`

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov Только хамить не нужно. Прочитайте в доке про оператор `$inc`. Ссылку сами найдете

Comment: )) С чего вы взяли, что я хамлю?

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov, наверное, из-за конструкции Вашего сообщения

Comment: Вроде нет нигде "элементов" хамства )). Ладно, проехали.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov, ну, тогда, держите ссылку, на оператор `$inc` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/index.html . В двух словах: он работает как знак `+`

Comment: Да это я знаю. Но ведь вы жестко указывает `1`.

Comment: Представьте, что в коллекции есть конкретный документ с именем `apple`. А в массиве `data` такой элемент имеет `count` равный `5` (как в вашем примере). Разве инкрементировать не на 5 необходимо? В вашем же случае, всегда будет `+1`.

Comment: Я в своем ответе заменил `set` на `inc`. Насколько я понимаю, именно этого хочет автор вопроса.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov, соль не в `$inc`, а в настройках `upsert` - имеено, она указывает, что делать, если документ не найден. По умолчанию, она `false`, а `true`  - означает, что нужно документ вставить

Comment: Я с вами полностью согласен, знаю как работает `inc` с `upsert`. Я про другое. Но я вижу, что вы решили просто путь показать, а полное решение автор сам уже должен додумать. Если так, то без вопросов.